# Separar string Python, parametros independientes

Tags: python, array, string

En primer lugar gracias por la atención, y por otro lado no creo que sea tan difícil lo que trato de hacer, sólo que he estado atrapado durante 2 días y no sé qué hacer.

Tengo un software al cual se agrega un script. Este software pasa 2 parámetros

`sys.argv [1]` y `sys.argv [2]`

Pero el software pasa los 2 parámetros como una cadena.

EDITAR:

> ¿Cómo puedo separar estos 2 parámetros para interpretarlos como
>   parámetros independientes?

Mi software usa la variable $MOST_REPEATED$ con este formato: 192.168.1.1 1.2.3.4 y necesito que lo coja para cada uno de ellos.

Cabe mencionar que no tengo acceso al codigo del programa que almacena esos datos en la variable $MOST_REPEATED$

```
 host = sys.argv [1]
 ip_src = sys.argv [2]
```

Está hecho en python.

Comment: Hola Zero22, veo que acabas de ingresar al sitio, te doy la bienvenida y te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para realizar preguntas es importante revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, un gran saludo!.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué significa que los pasa como una cadena? que se invoca al script de esta forma: `script.py "parametro1 parametro2"`, es decir con comillas dobles?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho exacto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no tienes forma de modificar como se envían los parámetros, lo que podrías hacer es tratarlos acorde a como lo recibes. Por tus comentarios, una aplicación invoca a tu Script de la siguiente forma:

```
python script.py "parametro1 parametro2"
```

El Script solo va a interpretar que está recibiendo un único parámetro, en cuyo caso debieras hacer lo siguiente:

```
host, ip_src  = sys.argv[1].split()
```

Recuperamos un solo parámetro que representa la cadena `"parametro1 parametro2"` y usando el metodo [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), separamos en dos a partir del espacio en blanco, lo cual nos devuelve una lista que asignamos inmediatamente a nuestras dos variables.

Comment: joder macho, me has salvado la vida . Muchisimas gracias!